# IPSec S2S peer B host cannot receive ICMP reply or access host resources on peer A

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, ipsec

I've got an IPSec S2S tunnel setup.  The VPN is connected, tunnel established.

Here's the network topology:

[image]

(for reference, I am **Peer A**)

Problem:

- `host A` pings `host B` and gets reply (this is not a problem, just giving context)
- **The problem:**`host B` pings `host A` and does **not** get reply (and cannot access resources on `host A`)

When `host B` pings `host A`, I can see the ICMP packets passing through the ER-X at `peer A`, arriving on `host A`, and replies being sent from `host A`  to `host B`, but `host B` never receives the replies.  The admin at **Peer B** says the replies not arriving on their side of the tunnel.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** the problem was SPI firewall on the peer A gateway